# Pandas dataframes: Create new column with a formula that uses all values of column X until each row (similar to cumsum)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A lot of times (e.g. for time series) I need to use all the values in a column until the current row.

For instance if my dataframe has 100 rows, I want to create a new column where the value in each row is a (sum, average, product, [any other formula]) of all the previous rows, and excluding then next ones:

```
Row 20 = formula(all_values_until_row_20)
Row 21 = formula(all_values_until_row_21)
etc
```

I think the easiest way to ask this question would be: How to implement the `cumsum()` function for a new column in pandas without using that specific method?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot because I don't know how to do it. The most I can do is explain what am I trying to achieve. I want to create a new columnB in the dataframe `df`. Each cell of this column should contain the result of a function that takes all the values of the rows of columnA until the row that is currently being calculated for column B, and adds them together (or multiplies them or applies any other formula, the addition is just one example, I know that I could use cumsum but that is not the point). Something like `rolling()` but not only for sums, but any other formula I'd like.

Comment: Does `formula` only depend on the current row value and its previous result, i.e. like `cumsum`/`cumprod`, etc. or does need all the rows directly?

Answer (score 0):

One approach, if you cannot use cumsum is to introduce a new column or index and then apply a lambda function that uses all rows that have the new column value less than the current row's.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': range(20, 30), 'y': range(40, 50)}).set_index('x')

df['Id'] = range(0, len(df.index))
df['Sum'] = df.apply(lambda x: df[df['Id']<=x['Id']]['y'].sum(), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no sample data I go with an assumed dataframe with atleast one column with numeric data and no NaN values.
I would start like below for cumulativbe sum and averages.

cumulative sum:

`df['cum_sum'] = df['existing_col'].cumsum()`

cumulative average:

`df['cum_avg'] = df['existing_col'].cumsum() / df['index_col']`

or

`df['cum_avg'] = df['existing_col'].expanding().mean()`

if you can provide a sample DataFrame you can get better help I believe so.